Switch user from from Windows Command Line
Sorry to ask about a silly problem that I have been facing. I am trying to remove this user from Windows command line, but nothing seems to work. I have this default user when I bought this Second-hand laptop. A Windows copy is already in there and an previously created user account was also in there. Now I can not remove this user account and replace this with my own. Every time I open the command line I am seeing this username. How I can get rid of it? If I directly delete it from "C:\Users" will it be a problem?


I have tried to create a new user but it is not showing in "C:\Users".

please add a focused question ... right now, it is unclear what your question actually is, because multiple different problems are mentioned

Those PowerShell prompts and Command Prompt are not elevated thus users cannot be created or deleted.

if all else fails, depending on the windows version, doing a clean install might be a good idea

You cannot delete the account you're currently logged in with. Also you'll need to add the new user first.  On an elevated command prompt and run

Create a new user that you want to use. Enter net user <username> <password> /add
Add that user to the local admin group - net localgroup "Administrators" <username> /add
Log on as the new user, creating its profile in C:\Users\
Eventually, delete the old user account - net user <username> /delete
Delete the old profile C:\Users\<olduser> - make sure there are no files you still need left in there.

As @LPChip has pointed out, that leaves that user's registry settings orphaned.
If you'd like to clean that up as well, before deleting the old user account run wmic useraccount get name,sid and note that user's SID. After you deleted the account you can run reg delete hku\<SID> - while that is possible on the command line, I'd recommend using regedit instead to make sure you delete the correct key.

While this works, you did not remove the registry entries. It means that if a new user with the same username is ever created again, that user will not be able to login. Not a problem for this quesiton, but someone else may stumble upon your answer and make a mess of things. Therefor this comment to warn them.

@LPChip The Registry is organized by SID which won't be reused - so I don't see the problem apart from dragging that useless data along.

@Zac67, LPChip is correct, if you do not delete the registry entry you will not be able to recreate a new user using the same username. I understand where you are coming from, but I've also had to deal with the scenario he mentions.
